# Exception for ajax global handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, global

I used this ajax setup inside my master page. now on every ajax operation the loading appears.
Sometimes I don't want to show the loading. How can i escape from the global handler?
thanks

```
var AjaxGlobalHandler = {
Initiate: function (options) {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    // Ajax events fire in following order
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $.blockUI({
            message: options.AjaxWait.AjaxWaitMessage,
            css: options.AjaxWait.AjaxWaitMessageCss
        });
    }).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, opts) {
    }).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        //if (options.SessionOut.StatusCode == xhr.status) {
            //document.location.replace(options.SessionOut.RedirectUrl);
            //return;
        //}

        $.colorbox({ html: options.AjaxErrorMessage });
    }).ajaxSuccess(function (e, xhr, opts) {
    }).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, opts) {
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $.unblockUI();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: you have to override the `ajaxStart()` in that specific view

Comment: Thanks, but I have other ajax actions in that page which need loading be displayed. but i'll give it a try